# Button events slow and delayed on firefox

Tags: javascript, html, css, firefox

I have a button that has a background image. When hovered over the background increases, when hovered-off it returns to original size.

CSS

```
.bg-img-L {
position: relative;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-size: auto 100%;
background-position: center center;
width: 100%;
transition: background-size 0.5s ease;
-moz-transition: background-size 0.5s ease;
-ms-transition: background-size 0.5s ease;
-o-transition: background-size 0.5s ease;
-webkit-transition: background-size 0.5s ease;
}

.bg-img-L:hover {
  background-size: auto 105%;
}
```

It works perfect in Chrome and Safari. However, in Firefox there is a delay when the mouse hovers over the button. As well when the screen moves there is an even longer delay before the animation happens, and it is much slower.

Is there a fix I can include to make my site work better in Firefox?
Is this a common Firefox issue?

EDIT by request - The code that this issue is having is on each 'article' of my site. Each article is a post that is full width and a 25% height (stacked)

HTML

```
<article id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class('col-md-12'); ?>>

  <div class="bg-img-L" style="background-image:url('<?php echo $thumbnail_url ?>');">

  <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" class="linkage"></a>

   <!-- Put cat div overtop article -->
  <div class="cat-cell">
    <div class="cat-border">
        <h1><?php the_title(); ?></h1>
        <h2><?php the_category('  |  '); ?></h2>  
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="cover"></div>

  </div><!-- / bg-img-L -->  

</article>
```

Comment: Maybe it has something to do with the type of image file.  Is it a .png?

Comment: I would convert to png just to check, I'm not sure but it may help.

Comment: firefox has hardware acceleration issues with some devices - perhaps the issue is your hardware + firefox. Try on a different computer, see if the issue is the same (if you posted a working demo, then we all could try)

Comment: unfortunately it's on my local-host. I am using a 2014 Macbook 2.6. It's perfect in safari but delay's in firefox. I was wondering if this was a common issue

Answer (score 0):

Try this `-moz-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;`.

UPDATE:

You could try to use onmouserover to achieve the effect. See the [fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/jVeju/10/).

```css
.big{
    -webkit-transition:all 0.5s ease-in-out;
-moz-transition:all 0.5s ease-in-out;
-o-transition:all 0.5s ease-in-out;
-ms-transition:all 0.5s ease-in-out;        
transition:all 0.5s ease-in-out;
}
```

```html
<img src="http://kadeem.london/Content/Image/Money-Matters-Logo.png" class="big" width="100" height="100" name="image_name"
onmouseover="image_name.width='120';image_name.height='120';"
onmouseout="image_name.width='100';image_name.height='100';" />
```

Comment: That doesn't change the the issue. I'm not sure if this is a firefox issue or not